# Can't connect to Kubernetes Cluster on external IP

Tags: azure, kubernetes

I'm trying to access .NET Web API which I docker-ized and mounted in an Kubernet Cluster on Microsoft Azure.

The application works fine on local docker machine.
The cluster is running, my deployment was correct and the pods where created. Everything I check is fine, but I cannot access my application through the external cluster IP (Load Balancer). This is my YAML deployment file:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: ohmioapi-deployment
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: ohmioapi
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: ohmioapi
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: ohmioapi
        image: ohmiocontainers.azurecr.io/ohmioapi:latest
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        ports:
        - containerPort: 15200
      imagePullSecrets:
        - name: acr-auth
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: ohmioapi
  labels:
    app: ohmioapi
spec:
  selector:
    app: ohmioapi
  ports:
  - port: 15200
    nodePort: 30200
    protocol: TCP
  type: LoadBalancer
```

Can anyone give a hint of where to start looking for?
Thanks!

Comment: Are you connecting to the external ip address with the correct port? E.g. `http://externalip:15200`

Comment: Yes, of course @Charlino

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would give the deployment/pods port a name (e.g. `http`) and then make the service serve off port 80 but target the pod port by name... that way you don't have to worry about port numbers when connecting to a service.

Also, you shouldn't need or want to use `nodePort` if you are using type of `LoadBalancer`.

E.g.

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: ohmioapi-deployment
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: ohmioapi
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: ohmioapi
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: ohmioapi
        image: ohmiocontainers.azurecr.io/ohmioapi:latest
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        ports:
        - name: http
          containerPort: 15200
      imagePullSecrets:
        - name: acr-auth

---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: ohmioapi
  labels:
    app: ohmioapi
spec:
  selector:
    app: ohmioapi
  ports:
  - name: http
    port: 80
    targetPort: http
    protocol: TCP
  type: LoadBalancer
```

Comment: this doesnt change anything. setting the port by name might look a little better but the end result is the same. exactly the same thing I proposed.

Comment: Not exactly. Actually this solution did work for me, but i suspect it has to be with listen to port 80 instead of 15200. From that I figure out that it was a firewall setting problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the command `kubectl get service` to get all the information of services and check your service `ohmioapi`, the result will like this:

[image]

Or you can use the command `kubectl describe service serviceName` to get more details about your service, the result will like this:

[image]

You can check the port mapping in the load balancer and access from the browser via the external IP and port.

You also can use the command `kubectl edit service serviceName` to edit and check from the config file created by the Kunernetes, the result will like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure you need 'targetport' instead of 'nodeport' (or just drop it if the port is the same).

https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#loadbalancer

Comment: Thanks for trying but no, is not working. Any other idea?

Comment: i'm not trying anything ;) i've got a bunch aks clusters and it works for me ;) and its always just port or port + targetport